# Install apk in android device from java code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple application in Java to install an APK on Android devices connected via USB. Using ABD manually or installing from Android Studio it works fine, but I wanted to give a simple single button click install option within my application, I have tried following code but unfortunately, it is not working

```
    abdsourcesync = apkpath;
    progress.setString("sync in progress");
    System.out.println("Starting Sync via adb with command " + "adb"
            + " install -r " + apkpath);

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "adb" + " install -r " + apkpath);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
    scanner.close();
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process returned: " + exitCode);
```

I have searched around here but  I have only found installing an APK from within an Android application or from the android studio, not from a  core Java. or java web module

Your helping hand  would be really appreciated ;

Comment: Google is another good resource for working out how to do things like this

Comment: The posted code is plain Java code on PC side and it looks good, why don't you use it or what are the problems with it? Edit your question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I have used it and I got the following error  Cannot run program "adb": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Hi guys, I have found the simple solution to do this task find it out from following URL [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824445/installing-apk-on-android-device-via-adb-with-java-program-on-linux/54167709#54167709) There I explained about the whole process and steps

Answer (score 5):

**Do not forget about runtime permissions**

This simple example works for me for API 28. 
It opens an apk file to install from "Download folder"

**For simplification:**
Download the apk file for application you want to install to "Download" folder of your phone. (There are a lot of instructions to do it programmaticaly, ot you can do it manualy)

**TO DO**

- *Create new project*
- *Add a button to MainActivity*
- *Create xml folder in res folder and create a file_paths.xml file there*
- *Use the code bellow*
- *Enjoy =)*

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.teko.testcleanopenfile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // textView and button
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);textView.setText("Hello updatable World\n");
        (findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {RunAPK(getBaseContext());}
        });
    }

    private void RunAPK(Context context){
        requestPermissionsToRead();
    }

    private void requestPermissionsToRead() {
        // ASK RUNTIME PERMISSIONS
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},111);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            if (requestCode == 111 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                textView.append("Permission granted write\n");

                // Create Uri
                File downloads = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                File file1 = new File (downloads + "//app-debug.apk");//downloads.listFiles()[0];
                Uri contentUri1 = getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file1);

                // Intent to open apk
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contentUri1);
                intent.setDataAndType(contentUri1, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="download" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Install Application from Java code using below way.

```
File outputFile = null;
                    try {

                        outputFile = new File(<APK Path>);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", outputFile);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                            intent.setData(apkUri);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
                            Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "File not found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is code for java which is run into the Android application, what I am looking, a java application which is installed APK into the android device